# Creating one-way pairings of entries in a table (e.g., sports teams)

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have table SOCER and has one column TEAM like below.

```
Team
--------
Germany
Brazil
Argentina
Italy
```

And they need to have matches with opponent teams like the following desired output:

```
---------  ----------------
Germany    Brazil
Germany    Argentina
Germany    Italy
Brazil     Argentina
Brazil     Italy
Argentina  Italy
```

How can i write the query?

Answer (score 2):

Using a hierarchical query requires no self-joins and only a single table scan:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/11049/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Soccer ( Team ) AS
SELECT 'Germany' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Brazil' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Argentina' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Italy' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT prior team AS team,
       team AS opponent
FROM   (
  SELECT team, ROWNUM AS rn
  FROM   Soccer
)
WHERE LEVEL = 2
CONNECT BY prior rn < rn
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/11049/2/0)**:

```
|      TEAM |  OPPONENT |
|-----------|-----------|
|   Germany |    Brazil |
|   Germany | Argentina |
|   Germany |     Italy |
|    Brazil | Argentina |
|    Brazil |     Italy |
| Argentina |     Italy |
```

**Query 2**: or, more simply, but with a different ordering

```
SELECT prior team AS team,
       team AS opponent
FROM   Soccer
WHERE LEVEL = 2
CONNECT BY prior team < team
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/11049/2/1)**:

```
|      TEAM | OPPONENT |
|-----------|----------|
| Argentina |   Brazil |
| Argentina |  Germany |
| Argentina |    Italy |
|    Brazil |  Germany |
|    Brazil |    Italy |
|   Germany |    Italy |
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT soccer.team, soccer2.team
FROM soccer, soccer as soccer2
WHERE soccer.team > soccer2.team
```

Quick and dirty. If you want to order it in a specific order, add a ORDER BY, for example:

```
SELECT soccer.team, soccer2.team
FROM soccer, soccer as soccer2
WHERE soccer.team > soccer2.team
ORDER BY soccer.team, soccer2.team
```

Not your question, but another helpfull query is a query for a competition where you have a return match (i.e. the teams play against each other twice:

```
SELECT soccer.team, soccer2.team
FROM soccer, soccer as soccer2
WHERE soccer.team <> soccer2.team
```

It is basicly the same query, but <> instead of >

Comment: The `<>` condition is redundant when ANDed with the `>` condition.

Comment: Good point, edited

Comment: You do not need to use legacy comma joins - you can rewrite the query using ANSI 92 syntax (now over 2 decades old), which can greatly simplify more complex queries, as `SELECT soccer.team, soccer2.team FROM soccer INNER JOIN soccer AS soccer2 ON ( soccer.team > soccer2.team )`

Comment: @MT0 I find myself using both syntaxes. I use the old syntax mostly when the queries are small and easy. Old habits die hard, I guess. But technically the old method is just as valid as the modern one.

Answer (score 1):

```
SQL> with soccer (team) as
  2    (select 'Germany'    from dual union
  3     select 'Brazil'     from dual union
  4     select 'Argentina'  from dual union
  5     select 'Italy'      from dual
  6    )
  7  select h.team, g.team
  8  from soccer h cross join soccer g
  9  where h.team > g.team;

TEAM      TEAM
--------- ---------
Italy     Germany
Italy     Brazil
Italy     Argentina
Germany   Brazil
Germany   Argentina
Brazil    Argentina

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: This query is cumbersome and not dynamic (you have to change the query if teams change).

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean. Could you, please, explain it, @HappyMe?

Comment: @HappyMe - The CTE is just included to make the example self-contained. It is more succinct than including `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT INTO` statements just to set up the test data.

Comment: Ah, CTE! Thank you, @Gord.

Comment: @littlefoot Your query has a table declaration at the start. There already is a table with rows. For a beginner this may look strange. You do not know the knowledge level of the orgiginal asker. I somewhat agree with gord thompson, but I was regularly confused by these kind of things when i was a beginner :-)

Comment: I don't think that there's anything wrong with my answer to the question, @HappyMe. As of the OP's knowledge, it probably isn't at the *high* level currently, regarding the question (s)he posted, but - hopefully - will improve.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need the desired output to match your question then you'll need to match on ROWNUM, not on the team names:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7a490/8)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE SOCER
    ("Team" varchar2(9))
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO SOCER ("Team")
         VALUES ('Germany')
    INTO SOCER ("Team")
         VALUES ('Brazil')
    INTO SOCER ("Team")
         VALUES ('Argentina')
    INTO SOCER ("Team")
         VALUES ('Italy')
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT a."Team" AS Team1, b."Team" AS Team2
FROM 
  (SELECT "Team", ROWNUM AS rn FROM SOCER) a
  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT "Team", ROWNUM AS rn FROM SOCER) b
    ON b.rn > a.rn;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7a490/8/0)**:

```
|     TEAM1 |     TEAM2 |
|-----------|-----------|
|   Germany |    Brazil |
|   Germany | Argentina |
|   Germany |     Italy |
|    Brazil | Argentina |
|    Brazil |     Italy |
| Argentina |     Italy |
```

Comment: Right; though, two objections, if I may. **#1**: I'd avoid creating (objects in general, but - in this case) columns whose names are enclosed into double quotes. No benefit, a lot of problems. **#2**: currently, it works. Though, if you *deleted* something and *inserted* it back (for example, `delete from socer where substr(team, 1, 1) < 'G';` and insert Argentina and Brazil back, order won't be the same any more. No more objections (thus, an upvote).

Comment: @Littlefoot - Thanks for the comments. I agree about the column names; I had to add the quotes to get the SQL Fiddle to work. I was aware of such pitfalls with PostgreSQL but not with Oracle. (I don't have much experience with Oracle.) Also good point re: ordering, although if the source table changes then the output order would still match the (new) input order, right? *(Insert obligatory warning about relying on the order of results without having an explicit ORDER BY ....)*

Comment: Right; I don't think that you did anything *wrong*, just thought I should mention that.

Comment: You do not need to use legacy comma joins - you can rewrite the query using ANSI 92 syntax, which can greatly simplify more complex queries, as `SELECT ... FROM (...) a INNER JOIN (...) b ON (b.rn > a.rn)`

Comment: @MT0 - Thanks. Answer updated.

Answer (score -1):

You try this code

```
select a.team, b.team from socer a, socer b;
```

Comment: That will match teams against themselves and also include reverse fixtures